# Unable to locate package gnuradio, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

The instruction on the gnuradio website says I can install gnuradio just by call *'apt-get install gnuradio.'* But I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnuradio
```

I also tried *'sudo apt-get install gnuradio'*. no luck.

My system is ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Gnuradio&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all reveals that it's in *universe* which you need to enable separately.

Comment: Belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: But that is already enabled on my system...

Comment: In the future, this really is a question for askubuntu, or, better yet, the GNURadio mailing list (discuss-gnuradio). It's a packaging question, not a question about programming.

Comment: @tripleee although it is listed in universe, it is not. trying to to install with universe enabled and updated will fail

Comment: The link I provided is for Saucy (Ubuntu 13.10); the package appears to be unavailable in 13.04 and earlier. Find a backport (such as in Oprea's answer) or upgrade to the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: @tripleee It is available in all versions  (lucid (10.04) , quantal and later (12.10+) ) except precise 12.04 !

Comment: This question is really about development . GNU Radio is a software defined radio development tools. GNU Radio is programmed in C++ or python.

Answer (score 5):

Add Ettus repository

```
bash -c 'echo "deb http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/repo/uhd/ubuntu/`lsb_release -cs` `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ettus.list'
bash -c 'echo "deb http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/repo/gnuradio/ubuntu/`lsb_release -cs` `lsb_release -cs` main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ettus.list'

apt-get update
apt-get install -t `lsb_release -cs` uhd gnuradio
```

Comment: Thank you. that works. I'm still a little confused toward the end of the installation instruction (the standalone uhd). Did you get it from [here](http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki/GNURadio_Linux)?

Comment: @theninety'er - UHD is always stand-alone from GNURadio. GR contains a component to use UHD, called GR-UHD, but it requires that UHD already be installed to use it.